# Форматирование EditText в денежный формат

Tags: android, kotlin

Стиль EditText

```
   <style name="MyEditStyle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">number</item>
        <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    </style>
```

Мне нужно показывать клавиатуру ввода цифр (только цифр) и при вводе автоматически форматировать вводимую строку в "денежный" формат.

Например ввел я

3000 автоматам стало 3 000

300 автоматам стало 300

30000 автоматам стало 30 000

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Нужно добавить к EditText TextWatcher и внутри делаете с введенным текстом то, что хотите. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое решение выбрал для себя

```
class MoneyTextWatcher(
    private val editText: EditText,
    var sep: String
) : TextWatcher {

    private val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US) as DecimalFormat



    init {
        formatter.applyPattern("#,###,###,###")
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        try {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            var origStr = s.toString()
            origStr = origStr.replace(",".toRegex(), "").replace(" ".toRegex(), "")
            val longValue = origStr.toLong()
            var str = formatter.format(longValue)
            if (str.contains(",")) {
                str = str.replace(",".toRegex(), sep)
            }
            editText.setText(str)
            editText.setSelection(editText.text.length)
        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
            nfe.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Используется так

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(MoneyTextWatcher(editText, " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Не занимайтесь велосипедостроительством, возьмите готовую библиотеку, [например эту](https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText):

```
<com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mask="### ### ###" />
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но ради каждой мелочной фичи тащить сторонние библиотеки не очень хороший вариант. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс вроде такого

```
public class FormatManager {

public String formatPrice(int price) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###", symbols);
    return df.format(price);
}
```

}

после завершения ввода текста в нужном месте:

```
FormatManager fm = new FormatManager();
String result = fm.formatPrice(editText.toString());
```